# Optimal View Design To Find Mismatches Between Two Sets of Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

A bit of background...my company utilizes a piece of software that stores information about a mortgage loan in independent fields. These fields are broken up across many tables in the loan database.

My current dilemma revolves around designing a view(s) that will allow me to find mismatched data on a subset of loans from the underwriting side of our software and the lock side of our software.

Here is a quick example of the data returned from the two views that already exist:

UW View

```
transID | DTIField | LTVField | MIField  
50000   | 37.5     | 85.0     | 1
```

Lock View

```
transID | DTIField | LTVField | MIField  
50000   | 42.0     | 85.0     | 0
```

In the above situation, the view should return the fields that are not matching (in this case the DTIField and the MIField). I have built a comparison view that uses a series of CASE statements to return either a 0 for not matched or a 1 for matched already:

```
transID | DTIField | LTVField | MIField  
50000   | 0        | 1        | 0
```

This is fine in itself but it is creating a bit of an issue downstream on the reporting side. We want to be able to build a report that would display only those transIDs that have mismatched data and show which columns are not matched. Crystal Reports is the reporting solution in question.

Some specifics about the data sets...we have 27 items of the loan that we are comparing (so a total 54 fields). There are over 4000 loans in the system and growing. There are already indexes on the transID fields.

How would you structure the view to return all the data needed for the report? We can do a good amount of work in Crystal Reports but ideally much of the logic would be handled in MSSQL.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I don't see any puzzle here, unless you say, you don't want to hard code 54 fields. you can get the desired result using simple join.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be no issue in comparing the 27 columns for a given row. Since you'll be reading the row just once and comparing the columns on that row in both the tables, it shouldn't really pose any performance issues. You can use some `hash` functions [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms174415(v=sql.100).aspx) to assign a hash value to the combination of these 27 fields in both the tables and then use this field to compare which rows should be returned by the view. This should result in some performance improvement. Testing will reveal more.